# Probability problem with a die

Tags: combinatorics

I've been practicing probability problems lately and I came to this problem

> A number is formed in the following way. You throw a six-sided
>   die until you get a 6 or until you have thrown it three times at the
>   most. A sequence of dice throws form either one, two or three-digit
>   numbers. How many distinct numbers can be formed as a result of
>   this experiment?

I thought about solving the problem this way:

First if the die is thrown and if it lands on a 6 that's the first number. 
Other numbers are:
16
26 36 46 56.
Now the next numbers are: 123, 124, 125... and so on. 
Is this right and if it is how do you approach this problem faster. It would take too long to solve it this way.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  There are three cases. First roll is a 6. First roll is not a 6 and second roll is a 6. First two rolls are not a 6.  You correctly counted up the first two cases and the third case would simply be 5x5x6 possible numbers, no?  (First two rolls could not be a 6).

Comment: This isn't really about probability at all.  It's combinatorics. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry you're right. I've been learning both of them and I'm little confused hahaha. Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 2):

For case 3: Not $6$, Not $6$, Any value.  (Then use the multiplication principle).

Answer (score 1):

$$1 + 5\times1 + 5\times5\times6 = 156$$

- $1$ for number 6

  - only one option
- $5\times1$ for [1-5]6

  - 5 options $\times$ 1 option
- <s>5*5*1 for [1-5][1-5]6</s>

  - <s>5 options * 5 options * 1 option</s>
- $5\times5\times6$ for [1-5][1-5][1-6]

  - 5 options $\times$ 5 options $\times$ 6 options

Adding them together gives you all the possible options.

Comment: Excuse me, but on the third case, Shouldn't it be 5 * 5 * 6 because the last number can be any number not just 6

Comment: Because it can only be the number 6, there is only 1 options. Therefor the 1.

Comment: It says "You throw a six-sided die until you get a 6 or until you have thrown it three times at the most.". It doesn't say that the last number has to be 6

Comment: Ahh you're read. Misread the question. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. You're answer really help me get the point :D.

Comment: You can write $5\times3$ or $5\cdot3$.  To write $5*3$ in MathJax or TeX or LaTeX or the like is vulgar.  The asterisk is a workaround for situations where you're limited to the characters on the keyboard. $\qquad$

Comment: In your last bullet point you need $5\times5\times6$, not $5\times5\times1$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm new to Stack Exchange and I haven't used the Latex expression that much so I'm not quite used to it yet, but thanks for the tip. I'm gonna keep that in mind later.

Comment: @Gigaxel : What is used here is not LaTeX; it's MathJax.  Anyone who masters it and thinks they've mastered LaTeX is in for a shock if they encounter actual LaTeX. $\qquad$